# How to check the being unique of the model without sending the model to the update method in laravel?

Tags: laravel, design-patterns, repository, unique, rules

Email and username are unique to the user.in validating the user update request،for email and user name I have this error:

"message": "Attempt to read property "id" on string",

this is method in UserRepository file:

```
public function update($request, $id)
{
    $new_request = (object)$request;
    $data = $new_request->all();
    $this->user::where('id', $id)->update($data);
    return http_response_code(201);
}
```

this is method in UserController:

```
public function update(UpdateUserRequest $request, $id)
{
    return $this->userRepository->update($request, $id);
}
```

this is UpdateUserRequest:

'username' => 'required|string',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->user->id),

Comment: Show code where you have `->id`.

Comment: How are you defining $this->user in the UpdateUserRequest?

Comment: What you are showing of `UpdateUserRequest` is not valid rule syntax. And nowhere in the code here have you attempted to get the property `$id` of anything. The error message tells you exactly where the problem is, I suggest you look it over.

Comment: please add a complete debug trace to know what the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `id` in the controller is the user ID that you need, you can access that id like this:

```
'username' => 'required|string',Rule::unique('users')->ignore($this->route('id')),
```

Answer (score 0):

It's actually because you don't have `$this->user`.
First better to check out if `$this->user` really exist with id inside.

You better validate like below.

```
$rules = [ 'username' => 'required | string | min:2 | max: 32 | unique:users,username, . $userId'];
```

Comment: With this  new validation  I have this error:   "message": "Undefined variable $userId"

Comment: You should change that to your own userId variable. Means the id of user which you want to be ignored.